# Java streams: Map<Enum, List<A>> to List<B>

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to do the following using Java streams:

I have a `Map<Enum, List<A>>` and I'd like to transform it to `List<B>` where `B` has the properties `Enum, A`.

So for every key and every item in the list of that key I need to make an item `B` and to collect all of them to a `List<B>`.

How can it be done using Java streams?

Thanks!

Comment: Map and flatmap?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use the opportunity to fully understand how flatMap works in the accepted answer.  Streams are ... not easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `flatMap` the entries of the map into `B`s.

```
List<B> bList = map.entrySet().stream()
    // a B(key, value) for each of the items in the list in the entry
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(a -> new B(e.getKey(), a)))
   .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to refer to `B` as `Pair<Enum, A>` for the sake of this example. You can use #flatMap and nested streams to accomplish it:

```
List<Pair<Enum, A>> myList =
    //Stream<Entry<Enum, List<A>>>
    myMap.entrySet().stream()
    //Stream<Pair<Enum, A>>
    .flatMap(ent -> 
        //returns a Stream<Pair<Enum, A>> for exactly one entry
        ent.getValue().stream().map(a -> new Pair<>(ent.getKey(), a)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect into a list
```

Simply put you can utilize `Map#entrySet` to retrieve a collection of the map entries that you can stream. `#flatMap` will take a return value of streams for each element in the stream, and combine them.

Comment: Why do you even need a `Pair` here? Its just complicating things... and no according to the question even if it is, it would be `Pair<Enum, A>`...no `List`

Comment: I'm using `Pair` as a real-class substitute for `B` since op did not define any form of constructor or such. Wanted to keep it demonstratable.

Comment: from the question ... *B has the properties Enum, A.*

Comment: Sure, but I'm not going to assume anything about the OP's code. I could've left a comment as `//construct b with the map and list entries` but again, the idea is you can take this code directly and run it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `forEach` solution for that would be :

```
List<B> bList = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEach((key, value) -> value.forEach(val -> bList.add(new B(key, val))));
```